# azure.datalake.store.AdlFileSystem not found in Spark

Tags: java, azure, apache-spark, cortana-intelligence, azure-data-lake

I am trying to use spark sql to query a csv file placed in Data Lake Store. when I query i am getting "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.AdlFileSystem not found".

How can I use spark sql to query a file placed in Data Lake Store? Please help me with a sample.

Example csv:

```
Id     Name     Designation
1      aaa      bbb
2      ccc      ddd
3      eee      fff
```

Thanks in advance,
Sowandharya

Comment: Hello sowandharya. Please read [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presently HDInsight-Spark Clusters are not available with Azure Data Lake Storage. Once we have the support it would work seamlessly.
In the mean time you can try and use ADL Analytics to the same job on ADLS using U-SQL queries. For reference please visit the link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-lake-analytics-get-started-portal/
We are working for the support and it is currently targeted for some time prior to summer 2016. 
Hope it helps.

Thanks,
Sourabh.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sourabh

Answer (score 1):

Tried hours today to figure it out... leaving it here in case someone else needs help!

For Hadoop 3.0.1, ensure that the below is uncommented in `hadoop-env.sh` file

`export HADOOP_OPTIONAL_TOOLS`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't configure `Cluster AAD Identity` for Data Lake Store when creating a HDInsight Cluster.

You can try to create a Spark Cluster of HDInsight with Data Lake Store on Azure portal, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-lake-store-hdinsight-hadoop-use-portal/.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did configure Cluster AAD Identity and gave Read, Wrire and Execute permissions